# PHP - JSON array can't return value associated with name without index

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json array that looks like this:

```
[{"name":"title_one","value":"something"},{"name":"title_two","value":"something 2"},{"name":"title_three","value":"something three"}]
```

I can get the array and access values like so:

```
$configarray = json_decode($configfile, true);


$valueone = $configarray[0]['value'];
$valuetwo = $configarray[1]['value'];
$valuethree = $configarray[2]['value'];
```

BUT I will have different pairs (and thus different orders) at different times in this json, so I would like to access these values by getting their associated name, I have tried variations on:

```
 $valueone = $configarray['title_one']['value'];
 $valuetwo = $configarray['title_two']['value'];
 $valuethree = $configarray['title_three']['value'];
```

but it fails and tells me I have an undefined index. How can I access these values by the name in the pair?

Comment: `foreach()` loop ?

Comment: for that you have to reformat your array in `key=>value pair` in such a way that  `title_one` become key and `something` become it's corresponding value

Comment: any idea how to do that? This is how the file gets written after serializing a form and saving the post data...

Comment: https://eval.in/598988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only have two properties inside of each json object you can do something like this:

```
$configfile  = '[{"name":"title_one","value":"something"},{"name":"title_two","value":"something 2"},{"name":"title_three","value":"something three"}]';
$configarray = json_decode($configfile, true);
$configarray = array_combine(array_column($configarray, 'name'), array_column($configarray, 'value'));

$valueone   = $configarray['title_one'];
$valuetwo   = $configarray['title_two'];
$valuethree = $configarray['title_three'];
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!! (never used array_combine before, super useful)

Answer (score 0):

The output of $configarray is

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => title_one
            [value] => something
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => title_two
        [value] => something 2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => title_three
        [value] => something three
    )
```

)

That is why you cant get by

```
 $valueone = $configarray['title_one']['value'];
 $valuetwo = $configarray['title_two']['value'];
 $valuethree = $configarray['title_three']['value'];
```

Using foreach you can assing the values to new variables

```
foreach($config as $conf){
   echo $conf->value; echo "</br>";
}
```